# Update a row with data from a joined table where each row is different

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to update a column in a table where the value is different for every row. The value I want to update the table with is obtained by an inner join to another table. How do I go about updating each row with the value obtained from the join, on a row by row basis?

Here is an example ....

```
DivisionId    DivisionName          LicenseNo
----------------------------------------------
1             Crimminal Law         NULL
2             Civil Law             NULL
3             Corporate Law         NULL


PracticeId      DivisionId     PracticeName     LicenseNo
----------------------------------------------------------
11                 1           Law Firm A       243527
12                 2           Law Firm B       364802
13                 3           Law Firm C       394843


SELECT Practice.LicenseNo
FROM Practice
INNER JOIN Division 
   ON Division.DivisionId = Practice.DivisionId
```

I know how to get the values I want but I am unsure how to get `Practice.LicenseNo` into the `LicenseNo` field in the division table. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
UPDATE Division
SET LicenseNo=Practice.LicenseNo
FROM Division 
INNER JOIN Practice
   ON Division.DivisionId = Practice.DivisionId
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set this up like this:

```
UPDATE Division d SET LicenceNo =
    (SELECT LicenceNo FROM Practice
     WHERE DivisionId = d.DivisionId)
```

This only works because you ensured that DivisionId is unique for Practice. If this is not the case it will throw a 'Single row Subquery returns more than 1 row'-like error.